# embed quicksight dashboard : (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RegisterUser operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying CLI based command to embed QuickSight Dashboard as per this link [quicksightembed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-setup.html) and this AWS Video [AWSQuickSight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZzS48whR78)
.

#### CLI Command :

```
aws configure

aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::842034702001:role/QuickSightEmbed" --role-session-name QSviewer

aws quicksight register-user --aws-account-id 842034702001 --namespace default --identity-type IAM --iam-arn "arn:aws:iam::842034702001:role/QuickSightEmbed" --user-role READER --session-name QuickSightEmbed --email String@email.com
```

Assumed Role is successful but while registering the user, I am getting below error :

*An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RegisterUser operation: User: arn:aws:iam::238683320570:user/String is not authorized to perform: quicksight:RegisterUser on resource: arn:aws:quicksight:eu-west-1:842034702001:user/default/QuickSightEmbed/QuickSightEmbed*

Please suggest how we can avoid this error.

Custom Policy which we are using :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "quicksight:RegisterUser",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": "quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that stands out is that the session name must match between calls.

In the first call you're using `--role-session-name QSviewer` but in the second you're using `--session-name QuickSightEmbed`. These ought to match.